# Cómo extraer datos específicos de una relación many-to-many?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Tengo una relacion many-to-many de las tablas Usuario, Supervisor, Operador y Cliente.

En este caso trato de acceder a todos los clientes que tienen los operadores que estan asociados a un supervisor y colocarlos en un select. Logre hacerlo, pero no queda muy bien en el select.

Quedan de esta forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los nombres quedan entre los corchetes y con las comillas, mi intencion es solo mostrar los nombres de los clientes.

Este es mi método del controlador:

```
public function create(){

    $supervisor = auth()->user()->supervisores()->first();
    $operadores = $supervisor->operadores()->get();
    return view('presentaciones.create', compact('operadores'));
}
```

De esta forma lo muestro en la vista:

```
 <select class="custom-select" name='tipo_user' id="tipo_user" value="{{old('tipo_user')}}" >
                                                <option value="">Seleccionar</option>
                                                @foreach ($operadores as $operador)
                                                    <option value="">{{ $operador->clientes()->pluck('nombre_cliente') }}</option>
                                                @endforeach
                                            </select>
```

Si conocen otra mejor forma de hacer esta consulta se los agradecería.

Comment: Cuando dices: **que estan asociados a un supervisor** te refieres a que los clientes estén asociados o los operadores estén asociados con un supervisor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El método `pluck()` retorna un array con los valores del key que le pasas como parámetro. Por eso obtienes dicho resultado.

Si es un objeto simple, puedes acceder directamente al valor que deseas:

```
<option value="">{{ $operador->clientes->nombre_cliente }}</option>
```

Pero si cada operador tiene muchos clientes, entonces deberías iterarlos, tal y como hiciste con operador.

```
@foreach ($operador->clientes as $cliente)
    ...
@endforeach
```

Depende de cómo tengas estructuradas las relaciones.

Comment: Si, tienes razón la solución fue iterar de nuevo dentro de otro foreach. Muchas gracias!